# Codeigniter: Ajax data is printing in log but not working in function

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm getting data through ajax who's function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Ajax post
  $(document).ready(function()
  {

    $("#submit").click(function(event)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hiddenValue = $("#hiddenValue").val();

      alert(hiddenValue);

      var update_name = $("input#update_name").val();

      // pop up Name Entered
      alert(update_name);

      jQuery.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "seasons/update_season",

        data: {
          hiddenValue : hiddenValue, 
          update_name: update_name
        },

        success: function(res)
        {
          console.log(res);
          // window.alert("i got some data ");
          if (res)
          {
              jQuery("div#result").show();
          }
        },
        fail: function(res)
        {
          console.log(res);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

The Controller function i have:

```
public function update_season()
{
    $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    if (isset($session_id)) 
    {

        // print_r($_POST);
        // die();
        $update_id = $this->input->post('hiddenValue');
        $update_name = $this->input->post('update_name');

        $arr = array(
        'id' => $update_id,
        'name'=> $update_name);

        //This prints empty data
        // print_r($arr);
        // die();

        $result = $this->model_season->edit_season($arr);
        // $result = $result->row();

        if ($result) 
        {
            print_r($arr);
        }

        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        redirect('user_authentication');
    }
}
```

And in Model through controller i have:

```
public function edit_season($data)
{
      // I am getting right array of name and id
      print_r($data);
      die();

    // but get empty variable if i try to assign value to it
    $name = $data['name'];

    $this->db->where('seasons', array('season_id ' => $data['id']));
    $query = $this->db->update('seasons',array('names ' => $data['name'] ));

    if ($query) 
    {
        return $query;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

The ajax seem to work fine as its printing the values of `id` and `name` its getting i'm not even encoding it in json, but i'm unable to get its value in separate variable. I wonder if there is any different method to get values from ajax data ?
When i let it run the whole model function without making it die i have following error:
`UPDATE`seasons`SET`names`= NULL WHERE`seasons`=`Array``
Like array have nothing in it

Comment: Post your controller code too!!

Comment: @Saty please check it i have updated the function

Comment: nothing happen i get same error 
`UPDATE `seasons` SET `names` = NULL WHERE `seasons` = `Array``

Comment: you just use  json_encode($arr) ;   echo it

Comment: but i don't have issue in sending response

Comment: then what is your problem ?

Comment: @jothi problem is i can't have those ajax sen't value in separate variable, and when even try to pass data through `data['id']` it gives error `UPDATE seasons SETnames= NULL WHERE seasons=Array`

Comment: try this  $this->db->where('season_id',$data['id']);
    $query = $this->db->update('seasons',array('names ' => $data['name'] ));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113402/discussion-between-habib-rehman-and-jothi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error in your query, you are supplying array to where condition, where it should be string,

```
$this->db->where('season_id ', $data['id']);
```

Also, it is not good to have unnecessary spaces (though CI driver internally trims all spaces) in conditions like `'season_id '` should be `'season_id'`

```
$this->db->where('season_id', $data['id']);
$query = $this->db->update('seasons', array('names' => $data['name']));
```

Check driver referance here: [Queries in CI](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html)

Comment: it gives error `UPDATE seasons SET names= NULL WHERE seasons =Array`

Comment: i guess the query is right but i can't translate the ajax's data to a normal variable ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1=  array('season_id ' => $data['id']);
$array2=  array('names' => $data['name']);

$this->db->where($array1);
$query = $this->db->update('seasons',$array2);
```

Comment: same db error with message " Array to string conversion " and `UPDATEseasonsSETnames= NULL WHEREseasons=Array`

Comment: okay it worked just perfect i had to correct that where query